# App rejected for inexistent copyright infringiment

Tags: google-play, developer-console

today I submitted an update for my movies app. I dont know if I can link the app, but basically it is similar to the more pupular MovieMate. My app allows the user to browse movies, read descriptions, add them to watch list and so on.

The update was rejected since according to the useless guys at google I'm violating intellectual property, while all the other movie apps on the play store apparently are ok. It frustrates me since I put in MONTHS of work for this app and got very few downloads in the first month. And now i cant even submit updates.

The data is fetched through TheMovieDatabase and I give them credits both in the app and in the store description. The API are explicitly saying that I'm ALLOWED to use their information for commercial purposes.

Now I want to appeal. What should I write to the google guys to get the update accepted?

Comment: If you are allowed to use them commercially, you should be ok. Please submit appeal with list of API you are using with "Copyright Use" link avaiable on API website, only displaying within app is not sufficient for appeal. Do not give links to other apps which are approved and working as they might have provided requested information already to google.

Comment: Yes, you can see here: https://www.themoviedb.org/faq/api. it is written "can I use the api commercially? Yes". If I win the appeal and i push another update in the future is tehre the possibility my app gets rejected again?

Comment: they will always monitor all apps for google policy violations and have rights to reject app.